# Как получить значения все атрибутов в теге?

Tags: c#, xml, атрибуты

Есть такой xml-файл

```
<Analysis Value="1" ReplyStatus="1" TestGroupCode="1">
  <AnaComment Type="1" Text="1" />
  <Lab AddressCode="1" Name="1" Address="1" />
</Analysis>
```

Необходимо получить значения всех атрибутов с `<Analysis>` по `</Analysis>`, включая дочерние элементы. Количество атрибутов как в коде. Тег `<Analysis></Analysis>` может повторяться, но уже с другими значениями.

```
<Analysis Value="1" ReplyStatus="1" TestGroupCode="1">
  <AnaComment Type="1" Text="1" />
  <Lab AddressCode="1" Name="1" Address="1" />
</Analysis>
<Analysis Value="2" ReplyStatus="2" TestGroupCode="2">
  <AnaComment Type="2" Text="2" />
  <Lab AddressCode="2" Name="2" Address="2" />
</Analysis>
```

В таком случае необходимо выводить не все в кучу, а построчно, как бы отделяя один `Analysis` от другого. Господа, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Пробовал вот так

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile);
foreach (XElement phoneElement in xdoc.Element("Sample").Elements("Analysis"))
{
    XAttribute Value = phoneElement.Attribute("Value");
    XElement Lab = phoneElement.Element("Lab");
    XElement AnaComment = phoneElement.Element("AnaComment");

    if (Value != null && AddressCode != null && AnaComment != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", Value.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Lab: {0}", AddressCode.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("AnaComment: {0}", AnaComment.Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

И вот так

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFile);
XmlNodeList nodeList = doc.SelectNodes("//Sample/Analysis");

foreach (XmlElement node in nodeList)
{
    string TestGroupCode = node.GetAttribute("TestGroupCode"), TestMethodCode = node.GetAttribute("TestMethodCode"), AnaName = node.GetAttribute("AnaName"),
    Value = node.GetAttribute("Value"), Unit = node.GetAttribute("Unit"), RefMin = node.GetAttribute("RefMin"), RefMax = node.GetAttribute("RefMax"),
    RefText = node.GetAttribute("RefText"), RefMark = node.GetAttribute("RefMark"), Finding = null;

    XmlNodeList anaCommentList =       node.SelectNodes("//Sample/Analysis/AnaComment");
    foreach (XmlElement childNode in anaCommentList)
    {
        //string Fin = childNode.GetAttribute("AnaComment");
        Finding += childNode.GetAttribute("Text");
        //Console.WriteLine(childNode.GetAttribute("Text"));
        //Не работает
    }
}
```

Comment: А что уже пробовали?

Comment: Что я только уже не пробывал..

Comment: ок. Только пожалуйста, перенесите это из ответа в вопрос, если данный код не является решением. Для этого под вопросом есть кнопка править

Comment: Без проблем))))

Comment: `<AddressCode="1"` это опечатка? XML такое не позволяет, имя элемента это только имя, если нужно значение, оно либо у атрибута, либо в теле элемента

Comment: Прошу прощения, да, это опечатка там <Lab AddressCode="1"  .... />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно простым рекурсивным обходом. Подправьте под свои нужды.

```
static void Main()
{
    XElement root = XElement.Load("<source file path>");
    foreach(XElement sample in root.Descendants("Sample"))
    {
        RecursiveOutput(sample);
    }
    Console.Read();
}
static void RecursiveOutput(XElement root)
{
    foreach (XElement e in root.Elements())
    {
        Console.Write($"{e.Name} ");
        foreach (XAttribute a in e.Attributes())
        {
            Console.Write($"{a.Name} = {a.Value} ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        RecursiveOutput(e);
    }
}
```

---

Если уверены в постоянстве структуры можно так:

```
static void FixedOutput(XElement root)
{
    foreach (XElement e in root.Elements("Analysis"))
    {
        Console.Write($"{e.Name} ");
        foreach (XAttribute a in e.Attributes())
        {
            Console.Write($"{a.Name}={a.Value} ");
        }
        foreach (XElement ce in e.Elements())
        {
            foreach (XAttribute a in ce.Attributes())
            {
                Console.Write($"{a.Name}={a.Value} ");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

---

В любом случае можно перебрать только атрибуты конкретного элемента, Так как атрибут не является самостоятельной единицей (или по-другому нодой) XML-разметки.

Comment: Я очень извиняюсь, а root - это что?

Comment: это ваш элемент "Sample" который есть в коде, но нет в примере XML. Или `XDocument.Root`. если хотите работать с ним, в общем разницы никакой.

Comment: А нельзя ли напрямую обратиться ко всем атрибутам? Просто мне с ними потом дальнейшие действия производить нужно. Я могу достучаться до атрибутов Analysis, но не знаю как это сделать с остальными тегами. Код в вопросе

Comment: @YuriGo нет, получить доступ к атрибутам можно только через элемент, который их содержит, т.к. атрибут не является самостоятельной единицей XML в отличие от многих других элементов, например текста элемента или аннотаций. Хотя если вы уверены в неизменной структуре файла, то можно это жестко прописать в коде, сейчас дополню.

Comment: Для меня главное чтобы результат был таким: Value 1, ...., Type 1, Text 1, Name 1, ..... потом сразу следующей строкой Value 2, ...., Type 2, Text 2, Name 2, ..... А выводилось в консоль примерно там Console.WriteLine("Value " + val, "Type " + type, "Text " + txt, .....);

Comment: Большое спасибо! Можно уточнить, в root получается я файл загружаю, а как ему придать конкретики? Т.е. мне конкретно нужно обращаться сюда "//Sample/Analysis".

Comment: а зачем? root - это элемент, который содержит ваши аналитики. В случае с файлом - согласно формату XML, он должен содержать ровно один элемент в корне, все остальные должны быть вложены в него. Ну и ни кто не запрещает использовать перегрузки использованных методов, которые позволяют фильтровать элементы по именам, как в вашем примере.

Comment: Просто код не совсем то, что нужно выдает. Он считывает но не те теги, которые надо...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49769/discussion-between-rdorn-and-yurigo).